# How do I add an action to Visio (2003)?

Tags: visio, shapesheet

In a Visio [ShapeSheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/concepts-visio-shapesheet), one can add actions. I want to create an action that updates the value of another cell (the position of a control). How can one do that? Does it need a separate macro, or can it be specified directly? And how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an addon or macro; you can do this in the ShapeSheet.

In the ShapeSheet, look for the Action section. If you don't find it right click and add it. In the Action section add a row. Set the cells to something like:

```
Action = SETF(GetRef(Controls.Row_1),"2 in.")+SETF(GetRef(Controls.Row_1.Y),"2 in.")
Menu = "Move Control"
```

Change Row_1 to the name of your control row. You can also change "2 in." to a reference to a cell in which you calculate the new position.

To learn more see:

[MSDN: Shortcut Menu Commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa200979(office.10).aspx)

[Bill Morein's: Meet A ShapeSheet Function: Setf](http://blogs.msdn.com/wmorein/archive/2006/08/09/693527.aspx)